# Why does not django delete one to one relationship?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, one-to-one

I have the following simple relationship:

```
class User(models.Model):
    fields here

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
```

I did the following in the shell:

```
user = User.objects.create(...)
profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=user)
user.userprofile
...<UserProfile: UserProfile object>
user.userprofile.delete()
...(1, {'accounts.UserProfile': 1})
user.userprofile
...<UserProfile: UserProfile object>
```

From the above, you can see that I create User and UserProfile instances. Than I try to delete UserProfile instance and it is deleted (at least seems like). Than I do `user.userprofile` and it's like it never was deleted.

After little digging into the Django delete method, I realized that when I do `user.userprofile.delete()` Django just deletes userprofile's pk and the rest fields are not touched. What I do not understand is what should I do in order to get the following result:

```
user.userprofile.delete()
user.userprofile
...RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile.
```

Does anyone have some ideas or code snippets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reload the user from the database:

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=user.pk)
```

That will refresh all its attributes including the userprofile.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Model.refresh_from_db`:

```
user.refresh_from_db
```

[Relevant docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.refresh_from_db)